# How can I send a list from backend to django template?

Tags: django, templates

I am trying to send a list of object to django template

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def index(req):
    labels = ['hello', 'yoooo', 'wassup']
    values = []

    chart_data = {
        'y': json.dumps(labels),
    }

    return render(req, 'index.html', chart_data)
```

Here is my django template `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var endpoint = "/api/chart/data/";
      var x = `{{y | safe}}`;
      console.log(x);
</script>
```

So when I use `json.dumps` it gave me a string of `['hello', 'yoooo', 'wassup']` and not a list.

Comment: You do not need to use the json.dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily [parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) the string to javascript object using `JSON.parse`

```
var x = JSON.parse('{{ y | safe }}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `json.dumps` in the view, and you also don't want the `backticks`` in the html.

```
def index(req):
    labels = ['hello', 'yoooo', 'wassup']
    chart_data = {
        'y': labels,
    }
    return render(req, 'index.html', chart_data)
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var endpoint = "/api/chart/data/";
  var x = {{ y | safe }};
  console.log(x);
</script>
```